# Get "Invalid derived query" error all over the place in our Spring Data JpaRepository interfaces in STS 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have implemented our repositories exactly as demonstrated in the Spring Data documentation. Everything was fine until we upgraded from STS 2.9 to STS 3.1.  All attempts to get these errors to disappear have failed, and in some cases they don't even make sense! They don't match any properties in either the interface or the entities used!

Here is an example:

```
public interface CreditNotesRepository extends JpaRepository<CreditNotes, Long> {

    CreditNotes findCurrentCreditNotes(Long shipmentDetailId);
}
```

The `findCurrentCreditNotes` is a named query in our entity.  This code executes perfectly fine.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "CreditNotes.getCount", query = "SELECT COUNT(f) FROM CreditNotes f"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "CreditNotes.findCurrentCreditNotes", query =
        "SELECT creditNotes FROM CreditNotes creditNotes"
        + " WHERE creditNotes.shipmentDetail.shipmentDetailId = ?1 "
        + " AND creditNotes.notesSeqNumber =  (SELECT max(creditNotes2.notesSeqNumber) FROM CreditNotes creditNotes2"
        + " WHERE creditNotes.shipmentDetail.shipmentDetailId = creditNotes2.shipmentDetail.shipmentDetailId)")
})
```

And the error we get:

```
Invalid derived query! No property find found for type ca.cole.freight.model.CreditNotes
```

Although this is just a flag (doesn't affect compilation), it is annoying and confusing.  Can anyone shed some light on this?  And explain it to me like I'm 6 years old!  ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's an IDE error explained in the following post:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?138585-Invalid-derived-query!-No-property-delete-found-for-type-java-lang-Object

In the meantime, you can turn off the validation in *preferences/spring/project validators/Data validator*  uncheck **invalid derived query** and STS wont throw the marker anymore.

Answer (score 34):

At the [post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/128352-invalid-derived-query-no-property-delete-found-for-type-java-lang-object) on the Spring Forum, Spring Team announced that

> It is already fixed for STS 3.3.0

I didn't check this version yet. But I'm using 3.5.0.RELEASE and the problem comes back! My fix is to uncheck **Invalid Derived Query**

[image: Invalid Derived Query]

Comment: Also occurs in STS 3.6.3.RELEASE

Comment: The issue is still present in STS 3.9.1 as well.

Comment: The issue is still in 3.9.4

Comment: Its still in 3.9.5

Comment: it's Still in 3.9.8

Answer (score 15):

There is also workaround for this. Add `@Query` annotation on your method definition in Your repository without JPQL/SQL query defined.

Here is example :

```
@Query
List<OwnerModel> findByFirstNameAndAgeNotZero(@Param(value = "firstName") String firstName);
```

In this case named query `OrderModel.findByFirstNameAndAgeNotZero` will be used. Your Eclipse error `Invalid derived query` should also disappear without need of disabling validation as described by @Tuan Dang

Checked on Eclipse 4.5.1 with Spring plugin installed for `@NamedQuery` and `@NamedNativeQuery`.

Comment: Pawel Deleba, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: query source string cannot be null or empty . your solution will not work

Answer (score 0):

I've just been going through this myself. Unfortunately, the implementation of Spring Data changed between 1.1 and 1.2. It no longer supports the `<repository>` XML declaration. You can set up a custom postfix, but by default, it expects a bean of class name `<InterfaceName>Impl`. If it can't find the custom repository implementation, you start getting errors like the one you're encountering. It's trying to create methods to query for objects based on names of methods in your interface.

An alternative is to back your Spring Data version down to 1.1 and specify a schemalocation of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd` in your XML.